# Remove parent or child element on page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, element

I want to remove the anchor element surrounding a block of code upon page load.

When the page loads, I want this code:

```
<h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle" style="text-align: justify;">
<a accesskey="W" href="#">
<nobr>
<span>Employee Announcements</span>
<span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ3"></span>
</nobr>
</a>
</h3>
```

To turn into this code:

```
<h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle" style="text-align: justify;">
<nobr>
<span>Employee Announcements</span>
<span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ3"></span>
</nobr>
</h3>
```

I have tried to get this working using unwrap but I am still struggling because I want to leave the surrounding nobr elements.

Comment: @f00bar - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Comment: @j08691 thank you ! ... Still that _This tag is not standard HTML and should not be used_. Same behaviour could be achieved with css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has an `.unwrap()` function that removes an element's parent.

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

example:

```
$(function() {
   $('#WebPartCaptionWPQ3').unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var target = $('a[accesskey="W"]');
    var keep = target.children();
    target.replaceWith(keep);
});
```